# system("clear") or system("cls") is not working in VS Code

Tags: c, powershell, visual-studio-code, gcc, system

I was writing a C code and wanted to clear my screen at some instant but in VS code terminal nor clear was working nor the CLS just it is giving a new line character
Code is

```
    printf("Hello world\n");
    system("cls");
    printf("Hello world\n");
    getchar();
```

The output is:-

```
Hello world

Hello World
```

And this is issue in all my programs I don't have any idea what to do with it.
This issue was both with code runner and debugger

**But when I ran the .exe file from file manager in powershell of windows the output came as I desired**

Why I can't get output in VS Code...????

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the built-in terminal wasn't fully compliant for the specific purpose of not hiding output.

Comment: If you replace `system("cls")` with `fputs("\x1b[H\x1b[2J\x1b[3J", stdout); fflush(stdout)`, what happens?

Comment: It might also be worth trying the various sample programs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/clearing-the-screen .

Answer (score -1):

I can't say exactly why it's not working, but I use the `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <stdio.h>` libraries.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34919111)

Answer (score -2):

Try including <stdlib.h> or  by typing `#include <stdlib.h>` or `#include <cstdlib>` at the top of your program. Hope ths helps!

Comment: In context this is clearly not the problem.

Comment: I already Included stdlib.h library,,,,,,,,,,And other functions like srand() is working. Even if I type system("exit") this is also working. Just this clearing screen is not working correctly